# Does incompressible in the smooth sense imply incompressible in the measure theoretic sense?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, volume

A smooth map $T$ is called incompressible if it has zero divergence and a measurable map $T$ is incompressible if $T^{-1}(B) \subset B$ implies $\mu(T^{-1}(B))=\mu(B)$ where $\mu$ is some probability measure.  Are these two versions of incompressibility equivalent in $R^n$?

Comment: What $\sigma$-algebra are you talking about? I'd assume Borel for there to be any hope of an equivalency

Comment: What have you tried?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These two notions are not equivalent, but there is a connection. To avoid confusion, I'll refer to the two cases as *divergence-free vector fields* and *measure-preserving maps* respectively.

As stated, any constant map $\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^n$ is divergence-free as a vector field, but clearly not measure preserving. It's easy to come up with lots of other linear counterexamples, some of which are invertible.

Instead, given a smooth vector field $V:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^n$, we can (at least locally) define the *flow of $V$* to be a family of maps $\Theta_V:\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^n$ which displaces each point along the integral curves of $V$. In other words, it is defined as the solution to the following initial value problem:
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\Theta_V(t,x)=V(\Theta_V(t,x)),\ \ \ \Theta_V(0,x)=x
$$
One can show with a bit of calculus that if $V$ is incompressible, then its flow $\Theta_V$ preserves the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}^n$ (i.e. each map $\Theta(t,\_):\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^n$ is measure preserving). This will not be the case for other measures on $\mathbb{R}^n$ (though some will give rise to a similar notion of divergence), and not every measure-preserving map is the flow of a vector field.

This notion generalizes beyond $\mathbb{R}^n$. For instance, a sufficiently nice measure on a smooth $n$-manifold $M$ can be described (locally, up to sign) by a nonvanishing differential $n$-form $\omega$. The divergence of a vector field can then be defined in terms of a Lie derivative of $\omega$.
$$
\operatorname{div}(X)\omega=\mathcal{L}_X\omega
$$
And once again we have that the flow of a divergence-free vector field is measure-preserving. This notion applies, for instance, to other measures on $\mathbb{R}^n$ with smooth nonvanishing density functions and to Riemannian manifolds and their canonical measures.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  How would you prove the part about flows?  I'm thinking use for t>s $Vol(\phi_t(B))=\int_{\phi_t(B)} dV = \int_{\phi_{s}(B)} |det(D \phi_(t-s)| dV $  and after taylor series for small t-s you get the last integral is $ \int_{\phi_{s}(B)} (identity+(t-s)div(\phi_{s})+(t-s)^2M) dV.$  Since divergence is zero, you get $d/dt(vol(\phi_t(B))$ is zero and for small t and $Vol(\phi_{t}(B))=Vol(B)$ then use invertibility of the flow.

Comment: That approach appears to work at a glance, but I would prefer to do a similar computation starting with the change of variables $$\frac{d}{dt}\operatorname{vol}(\phi_t(B))|_{t=0}=\int_{B}\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\det\left(\frac{\partial\phi_t}{\partial x}(x)\right)_{t=0}dx$$and then applying the [Jacobi formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi%27s_formula) (note that we can drop the absolute value since determinant is positive for sufficiently small $t$).